# Populate Email with form enteries Eclipse Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am newbie to coding this is my first app and would like to populate the body of an email with the entries from my form. I have been trying all day to get it to work just haven't figured it out, any help will be greatly appreciated. The log entries in console reflect the form input but the email does not populate.
Thanks in advance,

Here's the code I have so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appDiscription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/discription_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/employeeSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:entries="@array/employeeSpinner"
        android:prompt="@string/employeeSpinner" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/jobTypeSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:entries="@array/jobTypeSpinner"
        android:prompt="@string/jobTypeSpinner" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/jobDateText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/job_date_text"
        android:inputType="date" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/clientText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/client_text"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/arrivalText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/arrival_text"
        android:inputType="time" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/departureText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/departure_text"
        android:inputType="time" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/assignmentText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/assignment_text" 
        android:inputType="textPersonName"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/notesText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/notes_text"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/submit_button" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class AssignmentTracker extends Activity {

Spinner employeeSpinner;
Spinner jobTypeSpinner;
EditText clientText;
EditText jobDateText;
EditText arrivalText;
EditText departureText;
EditText assignmentText;
EditText notesText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    employeeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.employeeSpinner);
    jobTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.jobTypeSpinner);
    clientText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clientText);
    jobDateText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jobDateText);
    arrivalText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.arrivalText);
    departureText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.departureText);
    assignmentText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.assignmentText);
    notesText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notesText);


}
public void onClick(View v) {
    String employeeType = employeeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String jobType = jobTypeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String nameText = clientText.getText().toString();
    String dateText = jobDateText.getText().toString();
    String arrivalType = arrivalText.getText().toString();
    String departureType = departureText.getText().toString();
    String assignText = assignmentText.getText().toString();
    String noteText = notesText.getText().toString();

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            "Daily Worksheet");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Employee:"
            + employeeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Job Type:"
            + jobTypeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Date:"
            + jobDateText.getText().toString());

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Client:"
            + clientText.getText().toString());

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Arrival Time:"
            + arrivalText.getText().toString());

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent. EXTRA_TEXT,
            "Departure Time:" + departureText.getText().toString());

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Assignment:"
            + assignmentText.getText().toString());

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Notes:"
            + notesText.getText().toString());
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    startActivity(emailIntent);

    Log.d("AssignmentTracker", "onClicked " + employeeType);
    Log.d("AssignmentTracker", "onClicked " + jobType);
    Log.d("AssignmentTracker", "onClicked " + nameText);
    Log.d("AssignmentTracker", "onClicked " + dateText);
    Log.d("AssignmentTracker", "onClicked " + arrivalType);
    Log.d("AssignmentTracker", "onClicked " + departureType);
    Log.d("AssignmentTracker", "onClicked " + assignText);
    Log.d("AssignmentTracker", "onClicked " + noteText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only set fields like email address, subject and body.

You can compose body text from the fields you have and send it like below.

```
try {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("plain/text");
        if (recipient != null)  intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{to});
        if (subject != null)    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        if (message != null)    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

    }
```